# How to remove only part of URl string using apache url rewrite?

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

I have thousands of URLs that look like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/here-is-a-product-ab00007a1.html
```

The number at the end of the URL (before the .html) is the SKU. The site has recently been relaunched and these numbers no longer exist in the URLs.

I would like to redirect all URLs like this to their new version which does not include the SKU, example:

```
http://www.domain.com/here-is-a-product.html
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

**===== EDIT =====**

The actual sku format is like so:

```
aa00000a00
```

There are always **2 letters**, followed by **5 numbers**, followed by **1 letter**, followed by **2 numbers**.

The sku is **always 10 characters long**.

Comment: So is there any difference between the SKU and the last word in a product? Like are SKU's always end in a number?

Comment: Yeah, the sku is always the same format. Starts with two letters, has a series of numbers, then has a letter and a number at the end.

Comment: FYI, the original example of the sku was not precise, so I edited the question. Please see the EDIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-[a-z]{2}[0-9]{5}[a-z][0-9]{2}\.html$ /$1.html [L,NC]
```

You can also put that in your vhost/server config if you'd rather do that, just remove the leading slash from the rule's target so that it's simply: `$1.html`

Comment: Worked perfectly! I had to add a R=301 for it to resolve, but otherwise it's perfect!! Thank you!